# Exclude tag content from an Xpath object

Tags: regex, python-3.x, xpath

I got this HTML string:

```
'<li><strong>Réf. Robster+ :</strong> 3185W061</li>'
```

I need to catch the reference 3185I061. Impossible to use regular expression as reference might be in very different combination.

My xpath object (from scrapy) returns:

```
In [124]: xpath_var
Out[124]: <Selector xpath='//*[@id="reference"]/ul/li' data='<li>  <strong>Réf. Clim+ :</strong> 318506'>
```

and

```
xp.xpath('.').extract_first()
'<li><strong>Réf. Robster+ :</strong> 3185W061</li>'
```

How can I remove the  part at least?

For now, I've tried this:

```
xp.xpath('./[not(self::strong)]')
```

But it appears to be an invalid expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to extract text part without strong tag content. It's a bit confusing because you've got 2 xpath text function that don't return the same. In my case, I'd have used first `text()` rather than `/@text`.

```
>>> xp.xpath('.').extract_first()
>>> '<li><strong>Réf. Robster+ :</strong> 3185W061</li>'

>>> xp.xpath('./@text').extract_first()
>>> 

>>> xp.xpath('./text()').extract_first()
>>> ' 3185W061'
```

Which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do what you need?

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO('''<li><strong>Réf. Robster+ :</strong> 3185W061</li>'''))
>>> li = tree.xpath('//li')[0]
>>> list(li.itertext())
['Réf. Robster+ :', ' 3185W061']
```

Edit: I should have said more. Once xpath is used to locate the li element its itertext can be used to obtain whatever textual contents it has.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As I see here https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.2/topics/selectors.html#using-exslt-extensions scrapy selectors are also based on lxml.